# Monitoring Application deployment state through WLST in Weblogic

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

While executing below script to monitor my application status i am getting error:--
Script:--

```
connect('weblogic','weblogic1','t3://localhost:7001')
domainRuntime()
cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime/AppRuntimeStateRuntime')   
        $s = cmo.getApplicationIds()   
        print '####### Application ####### Application State\n'   
        for s1 in s:            

            cmo.getIntendedState(s1)                     
            print '\n'
```

Error Message:--
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  (no code object) at line 0
  File "C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\bin\dep.py", line 4
                s = cmo.getApplicationIds()
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Jython uses white space to identify code blocks, so the spaces at the start of line 4 onwards are the problem, it's telling WLST they are children of line 3 which doesn't make sense.  You also don't need the '$' sign to denote a variable ...

```
connect('weblogic','weblogic1','t3://localhost:7001')
domainRuntime()
cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime/AppRuntimeStateRuntime')   
s = cmo.getApplicationIds()   
print '####### Application ####### Application State\n'   
for s1 in s:            
    print cmo.getIntendedState(s1)
```